Radial Laser Beams Should Only Hit Visible Surfaces and Stop at Object Boundaries
I’m working on a Blender project where I’m using Geometry Nodes to animate radial laser beams scanning a complex geometry. All laser beams originate from the center of a circle and rotate around the Z-axis. The goal is for these beams to only hit visible surfaces and stop at the object's boundaries without passing through or hitting hidden objects behind.
The main issues I'm facing are:

Laser beams passing through objects: The laser beams are currently penetrating through the geometry and hitting hidden objects, which is not what I want. They should stop as soon as they hit the first surface.

Shortening laser beams dynamically: I need the laser beams to dynamically shorten and end at the surface they hit. I tried using the Mesh Boolean Operator in "Difference" mode, but since this is an animation with the circle rotating around the Z-axis, I can't apply (Apply) the Boolean Modifier directly.

Adapting to animation with Geometry Nodes: Since the beams rotate and the geometry is animated, the Boolean operation needs to be dynamic and follow the changes in the animation, ensuring that the beams only scan the visible surfaces.


My questions are:

Is there a way to dynamically shorten the laser beams in Geometry Nodes so that they only interact with visible surfaces and don’t pass through hidden objects?
How can I prevent the Boolean Operator from affecting hidden parts of the geometry so that the laser impacts are always flush with the visible surface?

I have attached screenshots of my Geometry Nodes setup to this post. I followed the tutorial from this YouTube link: https://youtu.be/CwVsgV-lwyQ?si=q9fq7ONQkT7Dy3T1, where the shader and Geometry Nodes setups are also shown.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!


I also faced the issue that i cannot add two object Info blocks because of cycle dependencys.

In one of my questions you can find a raycasting setup
